# Highcharts - Suppress points being dragged on drag event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts - it seems you can only trigger drag events if the appropriate dragDrop events are defined and enabled on a series. E.g. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dragDrop

How can I suppress the points actually being moved around in my chart? I have tried setting `allowPointSelect: false` and disabling both draggableX and draggableY but of course doing that don't fire any drag events. I have also tried `event.preventDefault` but no luck

What I'm basically looking for is to have a user drag over a range in a line/area chart from startX/Y to endX/Y and display the results to the user (which I can successfully get using `mouseOver` - a nice feature!)

Comment: Hi @raven, Could you explain your problem more precisely? What do you exactly mean by `suppress the points`? A description that refers to this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d8utLomc/ would be really helpful.

Comment: thanks. in that example you shared, how do I prevent the individual points actually being dragged/moved? as an example of what I'm trying to do with drag, see the google finance chart - https://www.google.com/finance/quote/AAPL:NASDAQ

Answer (score 0):

For such a feature, you don't need to use `draggable-points` module. A simple custom solution with a crosshair and dynamically added/removed plot-lines will be enough. For example:

```
  chart: {
    animation: false,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const chart = this;
        this.series[0].points.forEach(point => {

          point.graphic.on('mousedown', function() {
            chart.draggedPoint = point;
            chart.xAxis[0].update({
              plotLines: [{
                width: 2,
                color: 'grey',
                dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                value: point.x
              }]
            });
          });
        });

        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
          chart.draggedPoint = null;
          chart.xAxis[0].update({
            plotLines: []
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rsuj93at/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: I appreciate your expertise, but I'd like the user to be able to drag over a date range and have the difference between x and y presented to the user. I have also resorted to using mouse events as a workaround, but of course that doesn't have the drag feature. Is it possible to add a custom drag event in highcharts?

Comment: You can calculate the difference between `this.point` and `this.series.chart.draggedPoint` in a formatter function for tooltip. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c8ku2tsz/ The requested functionality is different than a basic Highcharts drag-drop, so it is really much easier to create it from scratch than modify Highcharts core.